# Modify Wordpress Custom Price Plug-In

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I tried modifying this plug-in for WordPress: 
https://easydigitaldownloads.com/downloads/custom-prices/?utm_campaign=documentation&utm_source=helpscout&utm_medium=doc&utm_term=1975-custom-prices-overview

**What I'm trying to achieve is moving the $ sign next to the custom price field or alternatively removing it completely.**

```
/*
* Hook into add to cart post
*/

function edd_cp_purchase_link_top( $download_id ) {
    global $edd_options;
    $default_price = get_post_meta( $download_id, 'edd_cp_default_price', true );
    $min_price = edd_format_amount ( get_post_meta( $download_id, 'edd_cp_min', true ) );
    $custom_price = isset( $_GET ['cp_price'] ) ? edd_format_amount( $_GET ['cp_price'] ) : '';
    $button_text = get_post_meta( $download_id, 'cp_button_text', true );
    if ( empty( $custom_price ) && ! empty( $default_price ) ) {
        $custom_price = edd_format_amount( $default_price );
    }

    if ( edd_cp_has_custom_pricing( $download_id ) && ! edd_single_price_option_mode( $download_id ) ) {
        $wrapper_display = '';
        $download = new EDD_Download( $download_id );
        if ( edd_item_in_cart( $download_id, array() ) && ( ! $download->has_variable_prices() || ! $download->is_single_price_mode() ) ) {
            $wrapper_display = 'style="display:none;"';
        } ?>
        <p class="edd-cp-container" <?php echo $wrapper_display; ?>>
        <?php
        echo __( 'Name your price', 'edd_cp' );

        if ( ! isset( $edd_options['currency_position'] ) || $edd_options['currency_position'] == 'before' ) : ?>
            <?php echo edd_currency_filter( '' ); ?> <input type="text" name="edd_cp_price" class="edd_cp_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $custom_price ); ?>" size="30" data-min="<?php echo $min_price; ?>" style="width: 40px;" data-default-text="<?php echo esc_attr( $button_text ); ?>" />
        <?php else : ?>
            <input type="text" name="edd_cp_price" class="edd_cp_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $custom_price ); ?>" size="30" data-min="<?php echo $min_price; ?>" style="width: 80px;" data-default-text="<?php echo esc_attr( $button_text ); ?>" /><?php echo edd_currency_filter( '' );
        endif;
        $min_no_format = floatval( $min_price );
        if( !empty( $min_no_format ) ) {
            echo ' <small>(min '.edd_currency_filter( ( $min_price ) ).')</small>';
        } ?>
        </p>
    <?php
    }
}
add_filter( 'edd_purchase_link_top', 'edd_cp_purchase_link_top' );

/*
* Add additional list item if variable pricing is enabled
*/

function edd_cp_after_price_options_list( $key, $price, $download_id ) {
    if( ! edd_cp_has_custom_pricing( $download_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! edd_single_price_option_mode( $download_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $edd_options;
    $default_price_option = edd_get_default_variable_price( $download_id );
    $display = 'none';
    if ( $key === $default_price_option ) {
        $display = 'block';
    } ?>

    <div class="edd-cp-price-option-wrapper" style="display: <?php echo esc_attr( $display ); ?>;">
        <?php
        echo __( 'Name your price', 'edd_cp' );
        if ( ! isset( $edd_options['currency_position'] ) || $edd_options['currency_position'] == 'before' ) : ?>
            <?php echo edd_currency_filter( '' ); ?> <input type="text" name="edd_cp_price[<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>]" class="edd_cp_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $price['amount'] ); ?>" size="30" data-min="" />
        <?php else : ?>
            <input type="text" name="edd_cp_price[<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>]" class="edd_cp_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $price['amount'] ); ?>" size="30" data-min="" data-default-text="<?php echo esc_attr( $button_text ); ?>" /><?php echo edd_currency_filter( '' );
        endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action( 'edd_after_price_option', 'edd_cp_after_price_options_list', 10, 3 );
```

See the attached image. This is how it currently looks. 
I really appreciate your help!
[image]

[image]

Comment: There are two sign for $ one is after textbox and another is inside button, My suggestion is to remove it using css.

Comment: Do you have an example how you'd remove it with custom CSS?

Comment: inspect element find its class or id of that element and add css for display:none

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the inspector. Any idea how to specifically adress the specific #text element to remove the $ sign?